# New flag called "similar to..." for questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

Quite often it happens that the answer to a question it exists as a combination of some others. Does it make sense to add a new feature to indicate that a specific question is similar or probably related to one or more existing questions but not the same? With such a feature we would provide extra reliable information (we are still capable of judging better than any NLP system I believe) to the Stack Overflow suggestions engine and later on retrieve more accurate suggestions i.e. better results on the "Similar Questions" section.

**UPDATE:**
I would like to provide some information over the concept above since I have the feeling that I didn't explain it sufficiently.

1. Right now many users are not aware of the *standard way* of marking a questions as similar since there is not a build-in functionality to achieve this. Currently we have a convention which is a comment with *Related: link* although I have noticed different ways to express the same, some examples are *similar link*, *possibly duplicate with link* and so on. On the other side I agree that flag has a specific purpose which is to mark the poor quality of a question and therefore instead of including it to the flag options I would suggest a dedicated link or button.
2. Many times is hard to decide when a question is a duplicate or similar to another one. Normally in these cases the user should use the *standard way* of pointing out the similar questions (if there are some) although I have the feeling that some of them decide to do nothing instead exactly because of the lack of an option which would make the process faster.
3. Currently the correlation between the answers is based on the number of matching words between the questions and probably some other NLP related algorithms. That means that the knowledge of the semantics of the code itself and knowledge behind the solution is most of the time hidden from the current suggestions system. As result, because of the lack of achieving that with an easy way, we have many orphaned questions (specially in combination with the second point). With the "similar to..." feature we would be able to create *clusters* of related questions and reduce the number of the orphaned questions.
4. Providing this feature we will be able to prioritize specific questions by *boosting* them in the "Similar questions" or "Related" window accordingly since we leverage the knowledge of the community. There could be even some metrics for the results such "how many times user marked that as similar" or "matching scale" under each related question.

Comment: `Related: <post link>` is more than enough though. It makes it show up on "linked" too

Comment: Is Related: <link> a build in functionality? Or a convention?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis the <> is just a placeholder. replace it with the actual link. Or for prettier formatting use the markdown syntax visible by clicking the help button on the bottom right of the comment box when making a comment. Will show you how to do prettier links, along with other formatting.

Comment: I am aware of Related: <link> @DavisBroda I am saying that I would like an alternative built-in option instead of a convention. I will update my question accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Flagging questions means typically issues with the post. If there's no exact duplicate, have a similar issue does not warrant closing the question, unless it's addressed in poor quality.

There have been many instances where I had a "similar issue to X" but X didn't solve the issue, but a similar issue helped solve it.

We already have a "related" section on the right hand sidebar in questions, which in my experience is pretty good, unless the question is new tech or obscure, but I can see how a sort of "sym-link" system could be handy for when the sidebar fails.